# How to Fix the error on saving category in magento 2

Tags: magento2.2.6

I need to show products of the sub categories in parent category page. To achieve this, i tried setting anchor option in display settings tab of category edit page at backend to Yes. But i get the following error

```
The value specified in the URL Key field would generate a URL that already exists.
To resolve this conflict, you can either change the value of the URL Key field (located in the Search Engine Optimization section) to a unique value, or change the Request Path fields in all locations listed below:
```

I am unable to save the category. How to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You try to create a category with the same name that you have. Try to add some extra symbol to field Search Engine Optimization -> URL key
https://i.stack.imgur.com/r0sqf.png